# PHP MySQL queries with variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

In my php I make this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionid = '$_SESSION["id"]';";
```

which results in an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Chore-Champs/index.php on line 6

Obviously there is something wrong with how I'm nesting the quotes, so I've tried different ways, including

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionid = " . $_SESSION['id'] . ";";
```

this still results in the same error.

Normally the first method would work with normal variables such as `$username`, but I guess that session variables are handled differently. What's the correct way to write this query?

Comment: You need to enclose `$_SESSION["id"]` in `{}` to protect the `"`s around `id` i.e. $sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionid = '{$_SESSION["id"]}';";

Comment: I would highly recommend using prepared statements see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "';";
```

A basic string concatenation in php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionid = '". $show. "'";
```

Comment: What is `$show` supposed to be?